# Hierarchy of a Java programme?

Tags: hierarchy

Is it fair to say that a Java programme is structured as follows ?

PACKAGES contain CLASSES contain OBJECTS contain VARIABLES.

The variables interact with Variables in other Classes through Methods ?

Answer (score 0):

No, not really.

First of you have packages - they can contain other packages or classes.
Each class can contain inner classes, fields (which are instances of classes or native types), static members, etc.
An object contains fields (not variables since some may be final) and methods.

Object instances (final or not) have methods which may have an effect on them or the input or some global state.

Dont try to over-simplify it - it is not very complicated but it is neither thiiiis simple.